# Count the facebook comments and likes for specific post and show them

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I want to be able to display number of facebook comments and likes for specific blog post. I want to do show them on the single blog page where all the blog posts are shown (titles).

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sharedcount is very good for those kind of things: http://www.sharedcount.com/

They offer a free account that covers plenty of requests: http://www.sharedcount.com/pricing.php

Comment: Thank you. I've managed to integrate comment counter, but I still have problems with likes counter.

Comment: afaik sharedcount offers both in separate return variables

Comment: it is __not free__ anymore.

Comment: it is still free. "Our Free Plan includes 10,000 daily queries.". they only changed the free plan from 50.000 to 10.000, but that was some months ago.

Comment: Very interesting, they changed from normal plans to only with $ + small line in end of page with 12px font size saying "there is free plan" :) Old view - https://web.archive.org/web/20140626002805/http://www.sharedcount.com/pricing.php